# How does OPENCV calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: c++, opencv

Does anyone know what algorithm is used for eigenvalue and eigenvector computation in the OPENCV library? Is it a suitable library for computing large scale eigenvalue problems?

Comment: You can always download OpenCV and check the sources for any information related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a function called cvEigenVV, which can be used to calculate eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues of symmetric matrices.

It looks like this:

```
double cvEigenVV(CvArr* mat, CvArr* evects, CvArr* evals, double eps = 0);
```

more info [here](http://books.google.nl/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=cvEigenVV&source=bl&ots=hSD25ojFNi&sig=Ds95h8oojG1G6AnsD7y0b1thuFA&hl=nl&ei=a3KcTaPLEIOWswb93syxBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CHUQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=cvEigenVV&f=false)

hth